# Android: RecyclerView inside RecyclerView, scroll to bottom

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, scroll, nested-lists

This is my case:

[image]

**Explanation**

I have a `RecyclerView`, let's call it **parent**

It has 2 items:

1. A static view, with static height etc
2. Another RV, let's call it **child** RV

Somewhere in the screen there is an **ADD ITEM** button. Clicking this button adds a new item in the child RV.

Basically, the parent RV will always have only 2 items, that is the static view on top and the child RV.

The child RV will have a dynamic number of items (depending how many times you click the add button).

Now, when I click **ADD ITEM** button, I update my `dataset` and call `notifyDataSetChanged()` in parent to show the new item added. I need to call this in parent RV, because there are views inside the static container (1st item of parent RV) which are affected by the *add new item action*.

What I want to achieve is that after calling `notifyDataSetChanged()` I want the whole view to scroll to the very bottom.

I have already tried all options with:

1. smoothScrollToPosition
2. scrollToPosition
3. stackFromEnd = true

etc... but nothing is working.

Do you know how to force the parent RV to scroll to the bottom of its content after `notifyDataSetChanged()` ?

Answer (score 1):

You could use just one `RecyclerView` with two different view types, the first being your static view.

I assume that your dataset is populated by a generic `Item` object, substitute this value with your dataset object type.

I think that the problem is related to the fact that by nesting a recycler view into another the scrolling methods do not work properly.

I'll post my code in Kotlin, let me know if you need the Java version of it.

This is the recycler view adapter to use:

```
    // Global variables
    private var itemList = mutableListOf<Item>()

    enum class ViewType {
        STATIC_VIEW,
        ITEM_VIEW
    }

    inner class RecyclerViewAdapter : RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder>() {

        override fun getItemCount(): Int = itemList.size + 1

        override fun getItemViewType(position: Int): Int {
            if (position == 0) {
                return ViewType.STATIC_VIEW.ordinal
            }

            return RowMenuType.ITEM_VIEW.ordinal
        }

        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
            if (getItemViewType(position) == RowMenuType.STATIC_VIEW.ordinal) {
                (holder as ViewHolderStaticView).bind()
            } else {
                (holder as ViewHolderItemList).bind(itemList[position - 1])
            }
        }

        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
            if (viewType == RowMenuType.STATIC_VIEW.ordinal) {
                val view = layoutInflater.inflate(<your-static-view-layout>, parent, false)
                return ViewHolderStaticView(view)
            }

            val view = layoutInflater.inflate(<your-item-list-layout>, parent, false)
            return ViewHolderItemList(view)
        }

        inner class ViewHolderStaticView(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            fun bind() = with(itemView) {
                // Setup your static view layout
            }
        }

        inner class ViewHolderItemList(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            fun bind(item: Item) = with(itemView) {
                // Setup your list items
            }
        }
```

To setup your recycler view call:

```
    parent_recycler_view.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
    parent_recycler_view.adapter = RecyclerViewAdapter()
```

To add a new element you'll need to call:

```
    itemList.add(Item())
    parent_recycler_view.adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
```

You should be able to scroll to the bottom of the recycler view by calling:

```
    parent_recycler_view.smoothScrollToPosition(itemList.size)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have had a very similar case to this one. While [@Luca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65345195/3944251) would be optimal, yet if it is not possible to have a single `RecyclerView`, like my case, the solution that I found was to `requestFocus()` at the last item of the child `RecyclerView`.

I had an `EditText` inside child recyclerview's items and what I did was:

```
inner class ChildRVViewHolderItemList(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
    fun bind(item: Item) = with(itemView) {
        if (isLastItemToShow) {
          itemView.mEditText.requestFocus()
        }
    }
}
```

This way whenever the `isLastItemToShow` condition was met, the `EditText` located inside the last item of my child recyclerview would get the focus, and eventually make the `RecyclerView` to scroll to the bottom.